# Elasticsearch, how to use filter gte on specific structure

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to learn Elasticsearch, and therefore I'm trying to find a good data structure, that will fit my needs for querying.

My data structure actually looks like this :

```
{
    "questions": [
    {
    "id": "n1-pain-score",
    "name": "Pain score",
    "answer": {
        "value": 3,
        "label": "Small pain"
        }
    },
    {
    "id": "n2-temperature",
    "name": "Temperature",
    "answer": {
        "value": 37.5,
        "label": "37.5°C"
         }
    }
    ]
}
```

For a given patient, there are multiple questions and answers.
Is there a way to take advantage of Elasticsearch filtered queries and say : 
`I want to see the patients that have a pain score over 6` ?

Note that I'm only testing and I still can modify the data structure to get what I want :).

Comment: A mapping you have for that data structure?

Comment: Well, not yet. Will use a mapping be part of the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do with a filtered query. A plain query will also do:

```
GET {index}/{type}/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "match": {
                      "name": "Pain score"
                   }
               },
               {
                 "range": {
                    "answer.value": {
                      "gt":6
                    }
                 }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following mapping and queries. Most important part - `questions` needs to be of type `nested` so that the `id` matching should of the same element of `questions`. Meaning the `id` with value `n1-pain-score` must belong to the same element that also contains `answer.value: 3`.

```
DELETE test
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "questions": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "answer": {
              "properties": {
                "label": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "value": {
                  "type": "long"
                }
              }
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "notAnalyzed": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST /test/test/1
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": "n1-pain-score",
      "name": "Pain score",
      "answer": {
        "value": 3,
        "label": "Small pain"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "n2-temperature",
      "name": "Temperature",
      "answer": {
        "value": 37.5,
        "label": "37.5°C"
      }
    }
  ]
}

GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "questions",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "questions.id.notAnalyzed": {
                  "value": "n1-pain-score"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "questions.answer.value": {
                  "gte": 3
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "questions",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "questions.id.notAnalyzed": {
                  "value": "n2-temperature"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "questions.answer.value": {
                  "gte": 38
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```